# Deleting numbers from a list based on another longer list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I would like to delete all elements of a list that are equalled to any element found in a bigger list.

For example, if I had A = {1,2,3,4,5} and B = {2,4,6,8,9,12}

I would like to get C = {1,3,5}

This is based on A dropping the number 2 and 4 because it is in List B.

Comment: look up `Complement` in the docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Complement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html):

```
Complement[A, B]
```

> {1, 3, 5}

Also

```
A /. Alternatives @@ B -> Nothing
```

> {1, 3, 5}

and

```
DeleteCases[A, Alternatives @@ B]
```

> {1, 3, 5}

```
Cases[Except[Alternatives @@ B]] @ A
```

> {1, 3, 5}